# Cleaner way to convert collection into another type?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a control, RadTabStrip, which contains: `public RadTabCollection Tabs { get; }`. The class RadTabCollection inherits from: `public class RadTabCollection : ControlItemCollection, IEnumerable<RadTab>, IEnumerable`

Now, I have a List of CormantRadTab. This class inherits: `public class CormantRadTab : RadTab, ICormantControl<RadTabSetting>`

My goal is to populate a list of CormantRadTab with the RadTabCollection. Currently, I have this implemented:

```
List<CormantRadTab> oldTabs = new List<CormantRadTab>(Tabs.Count);
foreach( CormantRadTab tab in Tabs)
{
    oldTabs.Add(tab);
}
```

I really feel like I should be able to do something such as:

```
List<CormantRadTab> oldTabs = new List<CormantRadTab>(Tabs.AsEnumerable<RadTab>());
```

but this does not match the overload signature New List is expecting. If I try and cast AsEnumerable CormantRadTab I receive other errors.

What's the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`Enumerable.Cast<>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx):

```
var oldTabs = Tabs.Cast<CormantRadTab>().ToList();
```

Or if there are some non-CormantRadTab elements and you only want to select the CormantRadTab ones, use [`OfType<>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx):

```
var oldTabs = Tabs.OfType<CormantRadTab>().ToList();
```

(In both cases the result will be of type `List<CormantRadTab>` - use explicit typing or implicit typing, whichever you prefer.)

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried - `var oldTabs = Tabs.OfType<CormantRadTab>().ToList();`

Comment: Uh-oh now I have to delete this answer before Jon Skeet tells me why OfType is pointless here.  (Or not, heh. :) )

Comment: It's not pointless, but personally I prefer `Cast` so that if there are *unexpected* non-CormantRadTab values I see an exception instead of silently ignoring the values.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't actually considered *that* possiblity.  Thanks.

Comment: I was just looking to to exactly what `.OfType<>` lets you do - to get just the items that are of the type you're interested in. A lot cleaner than my previous approach, which used an amalgam of `.Where` to get the elements of my desired type, followed by a `.Cast<>`.